# Make borders in maps fragment but not hide google logo

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm designing an app which relate to make borders cover entire screen of MapsFragment, i'm using GoogleMapAPIv2 and i didn't HIDE the google logo so, am i doing right ? is My app legal ? (Please see the pic below ). Thanks! [(Pic)Borders of Screen, but not hide the google logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay0lY.png)

Comment: Take a look at the [Personalizing your map](http://www.google.com.ph/permissions/geoguidelines.html) section on the link. It says: "While we encourage annotations, you must not significantly alter how Google Maps, Google Earth or Street View would look online. For example, you're not allowed to make any changes to the colors of the product interface or alter how imagery appears (such as adding clouds or other natural elements, blurring, etc.)."

Comment: #geradnimo - thank you, you saved my app.